# How to display json data in list view?

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, jsonp

I want to retrive data froma php page using json calling and display it in listview using jquery mobile. I am able to retrive the data  and also able to display in list but problem i am facing is that :
my data lokks like this in php file:
([{"id":"1","name":"Big Ben","latitude":"51.500600000000","longitude":"-0.124610000000"},{"id":"4","name":"Hadrian's Wall","latitude":"55.024453000000","longitude":"2.142310000000"},{"id":"2","name":"Stonehenge","latitude":"51.178850000000","longitude":"-1.826446000000"},{"id":"3","name":"White Cliffs of Dover","latitude":"51.132020000000","longitude":"1.334070000000"}]);

when I am displaying it in list it's showing in one row of list only. How can I disply the datas in separate row with respect to their "id" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var i;

for(i = 0; i < data.length; i+=1) {
    // do whatever here, the id is in data[i].id
    console.log(data[i].id);
}
```

Since you mentioned you were using jQuery mobile, perhaps you'd be appending `<li>` elements to a listview, in that case you'd use the `.append` method on your `<ul data-role=listview>`.

**EDIT:** As per your comment, change your each function to this:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
     $('ul').append('<li><h1>' + item.name + '</h1><p>' + item.latitude + '<br>' + item.longitude + '</p></li>');
});
```

And remove the `<li><a id="output"> </a></li>` from the HTML code.

However if you have more than one `<ul>` element on the page it won't work, so it is recommended to set an `id` on the correct `<ul>` element.

Comment: yes actually data is appending successfully but I am not getting how to populate in list with respect to "id". .. when I am displaying everything is coming inside one row. I want each item in separate row..  i hope u got my problem?

Comment: hanks rink. but still it's not showing in list. It's simply displaying data in simple <div></div> format. How to display in list ? it's seems like this one is working

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).bind('deviceready', function(){
    //Phonegap ready
    onDeviceReady();
});

var output = $('#output');

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://samcroft.co.uk/demos/updated-load-data-into-phonegap/landmarks.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status){
        $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
            var landmark = '<h1>'+item.name+'</h1>'
            + '<p>'+item.latitude+'<br>'
            + item.longitude+'</p>';

            output.append(landmark);
        });
    },
    error: function(){
       output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
    }
});
```

});